# Join Alias SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I'm having some confusion over how aliasing works with joins. After some googling I found that using a CTE gets me the behavior that I want but it's not clear why my initial try failed.

In short - why does this work:

```sql
WITH C AS 
(
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        dbo.Table1 as A 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Table2 as B ON A.Col1 = B.Col1
)
SELECT C.Col2 
FROM C;
```

but this doesn't?

```sql
SELECT 
    C.Col2
FROM
    (dbo.Table1 as A
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Table2 as B ON A.Col1 = B.Col1) as C;
```

Comment: you missed "SELECT <column list> FROM " just before 'dbo.Table1'

Comment: Yes... they're different - the CTE has a select and the subtable doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    B.Col2
FROM
    (dbo.Table1 as A
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Table2 as B ON A.Col1 = B.Col1);
```

Would be valid (although the `()` brackets are superfluous). It looks like you were trying to give a new name to the result set that is produced by the `JOIN` between `Table1` and `Table2`. There is no such feature in SQL - after the join, the result set is still referred to using the alias(es) that applied to the input result sets on both sides (e.g. `A` and `B` here).

You *can* create a new alias for the result set by instead making a complete subquery, as Anton suggested in the comments, or by using the CTE as you've already found.

Where you may be confused is that there are some other options that can be used within a `FROM` clause, such as `PIVOT` or `APPLY`, where you can provide a new name for the result set that is produced by such an operator. There is no requirement (nor option) to do so for `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will work,

```
SELECT B.Col2
FROM dbo.Table1 AS A
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 AS B ON A.Col1 = B.Col1
```